# to insert different amounts of silence at different positions in an audio file in python

Tags: python, audio, jes

I want to insert different amounts of silence like say for 50 millisec, 100 millisec and so on .. at say 2nd sec of the audio, 10th sec of the audio and so on respectively in python. 
My audio file is in .wav format

I found the following code :

```
def silence () 
    file = pickAFile()
    sound = makeSound(file)
    samples = getSamples(sound)

for sampNum in range(44100*2, 44100 * 4):
    sample = getSampleObjectAt(sound, sampNum)
    setSampleValue(sample,0);

play(sound)
```

this is present on the following link :

[link](http://www.cs.bu.edu/courses/cs101b1/slides/CS101.Lect28.Python.Audio.ppt.pdf)

This link is using JES framework

But i am not able to understand as to how to achieve the functionality using the same piece of code that I want to implement. Can Anybody guide me on this ?

Comment: I haven't look at your link, but the code you posted is rather mysterious. Questions on SO should be understandable in their own right. Links to help explain your question are permitted, but you can't expect people to read a PDF at some external site in order to make sense of your question. What sort of audio files are you working on? If you're using WAV files, then inserting silence is easy, since you can use the standard `wave` module to handle the data. If you're using MP3 files, it's a little trickier, since you'll need to use a 3rd-party module that can decode & encode MP3 data.

Comment: To take advantage of the code in that link - you need the JES sound explorer framework.  I think it's this one here as the author names match https://code.google.com/p/mediacomp-jes/ (I like Google).  If you get that installed and play with it, you might be able to get closer to what you want and come back with a more informed question.

Answer (score 1):

An audio sample is just a single number which defines the height of the audio curve at a particular point in time.  In your code function "silence" loads the audio curve from a file into a datastructure (array(s))  "samples"

Your sampNum loop traverses a segment of index values, retrieves the sample value for each sample index (getSampleObjectAt) ... then sets the sample value to 0 (setSampleValue) ... silence is canonically defined as value 0

Audio typically is sampled 44100 times per second ... so ignoring multi-channel and bit depth which I assume is handled by getSampleObjectAt ... this loop retrieves samples from :

```
(44100*2, 44100 * 4)
```

which means it generates a list of sample indices from 2 seconds to 4 seconds

To achieve your goal just calculate the needed range given where your silence starts and ends

```
goal A - start at second 2 silence for  50 millisec
       - start at 2000 millisec until 2050 millisec
       - from 2000 millisec to 2500 millisec

start_sample_index = sample_rate * 2000  / 1000
start_sample_index = 44100 * 2000  / 1000
start_sample_index = 88200

end_sample_index = sample_rate * 2050  / 1000
end_sample_index = 44100 * 2050  / 1000
end_sample_index = 90405
```

so in pseudo code (untested)

```
set_silence_from_to_in_millisec(start_time, end_time, sample_rate, sound_obj) :

    start_index = sample_rate * start_time / 1000
    end_index   = sample_rate * end_time   / 1000

    for sampNum in range(start_index, end_index):
        sample = getSampleObjectAt(sound_obj, sampNum)
        setSampleValue(sample,0);
```

so for goal A the call would be

```
set_silence_from_to_in_millisec(2000, 2050, 44100, my_sound_obj)
```

Comment: issue is that it is not creating the silence for two seconds on playing the sound .. can you identify the problem ?